# setting distances between (labels, values)

Tags: python, database, pandas, seaborn

I have to mention that I am a beginner by dealing with data frames, and I  am grateful for any tips :)

I have a dataframe contains names of files and their sizes (~8000 records). I am trying to figure out which bunch of files can be deleted or moved. so I tried to plot names vs. size.

**the problem:**

The labels and (most probably the lines are also overlapping, even when i used `linewidth` property)

basically, the code I used

```
>>> g = sns.barplot(y='size',x='files',data=df)
>>> for item in g.get_xticklabels():
...     item.set_rotation(45)
```

the resuls
[image]

the code with the `linewidth` property on samller sample

```
>>> g = sns.barplot(y='size',x='files',data=dfs, linewidth=2)
>>> for item in g.get_xticklabels():
...     item.set_rotation(90)
```

the result
[image]

I am using python3.5 and OS 10.11.6

Comment: That doesn't sound like the right approach to your problem. How will you decide which files to delete?

Comment: choosing the largest files, then decide either to move these files to somewhere else, or delete them if they are not useful anymore. to summarize the problem very briefly, it is a problem with my university account x_X !

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, I don't think a graph is the best way to do this. I would start by simplifying the dataframe to get the average size of each file:

```
average_size = df.groupby('files')['size'].mean()
```

You can then get the top 10 files (for instance) with:

```
average_size.nlargest(10, columns='size')
```

Comment: thank you, that helped much better :) Though I have one question please, could you give a hint about the syntax of the first command, since `groupby`  method has the keys inside the parentheses. i.e.: i didn't understand the `['size']` part in the command

Comment: also I was able to get similar results with the command: `df.groupby('files').aggregate(sum)`. that's why I asked :) thank you in advance

Comment: Adding `['size']` after `groupby` limits the columns of the output. I added this in case your original dataframe had many other columns, but it would work without it.

Comment: I agree that a plot isn't the best way to pick out the specific files from this large set, but it might be good to make a histogram of the sizes just to get a sense for what the distribution looks like.

Comment: @mwaskom agreed, do you want to add an answer, or shall I edit mine?

Comment: I think you've answered the question, my point about showing a histogram is just a supplement/bonus.

Comment: @mwaskom this was my idea actually :) However, problem is solved now. Thank you both